# Scroll View in Grid TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm completely new to iPhone development. I have a query regarding how to implement scroll view in table view. I'm using following code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ScrollViewViewController;

@interface ScrollViewAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    ScrollViewViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ScrollViewViewController *viewController;

@end
```

////////////////////////////////////////////

```
#import "ScrollViewAppDelegate.h"
#import "ScrollViewViewController.h"

@implementation ScrollViewAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

///////////////////////////

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MyTableCell : UITableViewCell {

    NSMutableArray *columns;
}

- (void)addColumn:(CGFloat)position;

@end
```

//////////////////////////

```
#import "MyTableCell.h"


@implementation MyTableCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        // Initialization code
        columns = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
        [columns retain];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)addColumn:(CGFloat)position {
    [columns addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:position]];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { 
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // just match the color and size of the horizontal line
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0); 
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.25);

    for (int i = 0; i < [columns count]; i++) {
        // get the position for the vertical line
        CGFloat f = [((NSNumber*) [columns objectAtIndex:i]) floatValue];
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, f, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, f, self.bounds.size.height);
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    [super drawRect:rect];
} 


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [columns dealloc];
}


@end
```

//////////////////////

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
}

@end
```

/////////////////

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

#import "MyTableCell.h"

@implementation RootViewController


#define LABEL_TAG 1 
#define VALUE_TAG 2 
#define FIRST_CELL_IDENTIFIER @"TrailItemCell" 
#define SECOND_CELL_IDENTIFIER @"RegularCell" 


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Add the following line if you want the list to be editable
    // self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    self.title = @"Grids!";

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    return 19;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyIdentifier %i", indexPath.row];

    MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[MyTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];

        UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 30.0, 
                                                           tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease]; 
        [cell addColumn:40];
        label.tag = LABEL_TAG; 
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]; 
        label.text =@"S.NO";// [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight; 
        label.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label]; 

        label =  [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 0, 70.0, 
                                                            tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease]; 
        [cell addColumn:120];
        label.tag = VALUE_TAG; 
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]; 
        // add some silly value
        label.text =@"Product ID";// [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row * 4];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight; 
        label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor]; 
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label]; 

        label =  [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(134.0, 0, 70.0, 
                                                            tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease]; 
        [cell addColumn:220];
        label.tag = VALUE_TAG; 
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]; 
        // add some silly value
        label.text =@"Product Name";// [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row * 4];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight; 
        label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

        label =  [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230.0, 0, 70.0, 
                                                            tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease]; 
        [cell addColumn:310];
        label.tag = VALUE_TAG; 
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]; 
        // add some silly value
        label.text =@"Customer Name";// [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row * 4];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight; 
        label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

        label =  [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320.0, 0, 70.0, 
                                                            tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease]; 
        [cell addColumn:400];
        label.tag = VALUE_TAG; 
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]; 
        // add some silly value
        label.text =@"Customer Product";// [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row * 4];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight; 
        label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];


    }

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     // Navigation logic
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

////////////

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ScrollViewViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate> {
}
@end
```

/////////////

```
#import "ScrollViewViewController.h"

#import "RootViewController.h"
@implementation ScrollViewViewController



/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/


// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {

    RootViewController *RootViewControllerLink = [[RootViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    RootViewControllerLink.view.tag = 100;
    /*  UIImageView *imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"winkler-gnu-blue.png"]] autorelease]; 
    imgView.tag = 100;

*/  
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[[UIScrollView alloc] 
                                 initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)] autorelease]; 
    scrollView.delegate = self; 
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.25; 
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2; 
    scrollView.bounces = NO;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO; 
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO; 
    scrollView.contentSize = RootViewControllerLink.view.frame.size; 
    scrollView.contentOffset = 
    CGPointMake((RootViewControllerLink.view.frame.size.width-320)/2, 
                (RootViewControllerLink.view.frame.size.height-480)/2); 
    [scrollView addSubview:RootViewControllerLink.view]; 
    self.view = scrollView; 


}

/*- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView { 
 return [self.view viewWithTag:100]; 
 } 


- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    return YES;
}// default returns YES
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{

    return YES;
}
*/
// not called if canCancelContentTouches is NO. default returns YES if view isn't UIControl

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

In above code if I set scroll for UIIMage then it works but if I set scroll view for RootViewController then it doesn't work.

Comment: Format your question first, and dont put all your code here.. StackOverflow is for helping where you are stuck not for code review. Put in only the relevent code and tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @lukya: ok, I did that for him this time. 

@aman: please format your code next time

Comment: Oh god. So much code... Nobody will ever read all that. Please be more concise in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read your code, please reformat it so others can read it easily.

What do you mean by a UIScrollView in an UITableView? Inside the cells? Still I don't get it.
FYI UITableView inherits from UIScrollView ...

What functionality do you exactly want to achieve?
I will recommend to read some of the samples given by Apple. There are very good and extensive examples specially regarding UIKit.

Comment: Actually i Want horizontal scrollView in Table View